# How to move list items using keydown events

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, keydown

I want to move list items in an editable div in html using keydown events for the up and down keyboard arrows. The up arrow should move that list item up and the down arrow should be that list item down. But i cant get the code to work.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lists</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true"></div>
<ul class="newUl" contenteditable="true" id="Head">header
  <ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">textContent</li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">chelsea</li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">window</li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">sancho</li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">goal</li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true"></li>
      <li class="newLi" contenteditable="true">lampard</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</div>


<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.addEventListener('keydown', moveList);
}


const moveList = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 38){
    e.preventDefault();
    var upLink = document.querySelectorAll(".newList");
    for (var i = 0; i < upLink.length; i++) {
        upLink[i].addEventListener('keydown', moveList () {
            var wrapper = this.parentElement;
            if (wrapper.previousElementSibling)
                wrapper.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, wrapper.previousElementSibling);
        });
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode === 40){
    e.preventDefault();
    var downLink = document.querySelectorAll(".newList");

    for (var i = 0; i < downLink.length; i++) {
        downLink[i].addEventListener('keydown', moveList () {
            var wrapper = this.parentElement;

            if (wrapper.nextElementSibling)
                wrapper.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper.nextElementSibling, wrapper);
        });
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Just trying to help you see the technique.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, bod, html, nav, M, I, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
doc = document; bod = doc.body; html = doc.documentElement; nav = navigator;
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// use the above as a library - you can put the below (besides the load end) on another page if you want
var edit_list = I('edit_list');
function moveUp(t){
  var p = t.previousSibling;
  while(p && p.nodeType !== 1)p = p.previousSibling;
  if(p){
    edit_list.insertBefore(t, p);
  }
  else{
    edit_list.appendChild(t);
  }
}
function moveDown(t){
  var n = t.nextSibling;
  while(n && n.nodeType !== 1)n = n.nextSibling;
  if(n){
    n = n.nextSibling;
    if(n){
      edit_list.insertBefore(t, n);
    }
    else{
      edit_list.appendChild(t);
    }
  }
  else{
    edit_list.insertBefore(t, edit_list.firstChild);
  }
}
for(var i=0,q=Q('li', edit_list),l=q.length; i<l; i++){
  q[i].onkeyup = function(e){
    var k = e.key;
    if(k.match(/^(Arrow)?Up$/)){
      moveUp(this);
    }
    else if(k.match(/^(Arrow)?Down$/)){
      moveDown(this);
    }
  }
}
}); // load end
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
h1{
  font-size:14px; margin-left:4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1 contenteditable='true'>header</h1>
  <ul id='edit_list'>
    <li contenteditable='true'>textContent</li>
    <li contenteditable='true'>chelsea</li>
    <li contenteditable='true'>window</li>
    <li contenteditable='true'>sancho</li>
    <li contenteditable='true'>goal</li>
    <li contenteditable='true'></li>
    <li contenteditable='true'>lampard</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```